# how to make gridview scroll bar always visible android 4.0.3

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity

I have a gridview in my activity and I wanted to make its scrollbar always visible.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the scrollbar always visible in an Android view add the following property to the relevant container in the layout xml

```
 android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarFadeDuration).

Specifically for `Android 4.0.3` API level 15 you can use,

```
   android:fadeScrollbars
```

It defines whether to fade out scrollbars when they are not in use.
 Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false". [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fadeScrollbars).

Using code the [View.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29) is what you can use.

Comment: android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"                                         Your inverted commas are wrong here if you copy and paste so I have fixed here